# In kotlin unit test how the assign lateinit var

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class RoundingTest {
    lateinit var rounding: (Double) -> Double

 @Before
fun initValues(){
    rounding(17.25)
}

    @Test
    fun checkRounding() {
        rounding(17.25)

       var rounding = MyRoundingClass.roundValue(Myobject);
        Assert.assertEquals(17.23, rounding)
    }
}
object MyRoundingClass{
fun roundValue(myObject: MyObject): (Double) -> Double {
        return when (myObject.isrouding?.needed) {
            ROUND_DOWN -> { value -> roundDown(BigDecimal.valueOf(value)) }
            else ->
                // no rounding
                { value -> value }
        }
    }
}
```

In roundValue method the value parameter gets assign from rounding(17.25) in My Fragment it works well but it test it does not work.
It gives me the below error
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property rounding has not been initialized

```
at com.appetizeactivate.android.rounding.RoundingStatergyTest.checkRoundingWithNone(RoundingTest.kt:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to change the type of `rounding` and make it

```
 lateinit var rounding: () -> Double
```

And assign it as

```
 rounding = { 17.25 }
```

Then use it as `rounding()` (mind the plarentheses).